# Target children within "this" parent

Tags: javascript

Assume I have 2 groups of `div`s -- both with click buttons, which when clicked, it will change the text content of the child within that group.

How can I accomplish that with pure javascript?

Thanks in advance

**HTML**

```
<div class="parent">
  <button>Click</button>
  <div class="child">Test1</div>
  <div class="child">Test4</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <button>Click</button>
  <div class="child">Test2</div>
  <div class="child">Test5</div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var button = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for(i = 0; i < button.length; i++){
    button[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        var parent = document.querySelectorAll(".parent");
        var child = parent.querySelector(".child:nth-child(2)");
        this.child.textContent = "success"; //just made up to show what I'm trying to accomplish
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to change only the first `div` element inside parent, here's one approach:

```js
var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

Array.from(button).forEach(v => v.addEventListener('click', function() {
  this.parentNode.children[1].innerHTML = 'success';
}));
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>Click</button>
  <div class="child">Test1</div>
  <div class="child">Test4</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <button>Click</button>
  <div class="child">Test2</div>
  <div class="child">Test5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also use the `nextElementSibling.innerHTML` instead of `parentNode.children[1].innerHTML`.

Comment: @MattWebb that is a very good option, provided that what the OP is trying to do is actually modify the element immediately after the button (I'm saying this because the code sample provided states that the change of text in the element is provided as an example).

Comment: @AngelosChalaris indeed, the flexibility with `children[n]` is probably preferable.

Comment: @MattWebb Using this property it'd not need some parents, but both ways look readable.

Comment: To that one who downvoted, let me know at least what's wrong with my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the `this` keyword to figure out which button is clicked, then get its `.parentNode` and afterwards its `.children`, select the second one (`[1]`) and change the text, like so:

```js
var button = document.querySelectorAll("button");

for(i=0; i < button.length; i++) {
    button[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.parentNode.children[1].innerHTML = 'success';
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button>Click</button>
  <div class="child">Test1</div>
  <div class="child">Test4</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <button>Click</button>
  <div class="child">Test2</div>
  <div class="child">Test5</div>
</div>
```